# Angular - create a new array from scope array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

I have an angular app which gets data from a JSON response.

How do i create another array, in a different format within my controller?

JSON RESPONSE:

```
"prices" : [
    {"month" : "01", "price" : 599},
    {"month" : "02", "price" : 1599},
    {"month" : "03", "price" : 2599},
    {"month" : "04", "price" : 3599},
]

$scope.prices = data.prices;
```

Into this for use in a calendar function **(new object for every object returned in $scope.prices above)**:

```
$scope.events = [{
    title: * * $scope.prices.price * * ,
    start: new Date(y, $scope.prices.month, 1),
    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    allDay: true
}];
```

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

OK, got the new structure using Array.protoype.map(), but it is placing double quotes around everything.

It is returning:

```
[{"title":599,"start":"1901-02-01T05:00:00.000Z","dow":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"allDay":true}
```

when it needs to be:

```
[{title:"599",start:1901-02-01T05:00:00.000Z,dow:[1,2,3,4,5,6],allDay:true}
```

Here is my code:

```
var reformattedArray = array.map(function(obj){ 
      var rObj = {title: obj.price,start: new Date(obj.month, 1),dow:[1,2,3,4,5,6],allDay: true};
      return rObj;
  });
```

Comment: use `Array.protoype.map()` to return new array with new structure

Comment: It doesn't matter if there's quotes or not - it's an object. Keys are strings.

Comment: It does - as this is being placed into a calendar script and the 'title' and 'start' are settings within that... so it's not accepting double quotes.